# asp.net MVC, redirect to view, view open new window to external url, it's getting treated as a view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Trying to put together a quick and dirty page to redirect to another website in a new window.

So I stash a url in the session, redirect to the page from mvcSiteMap, hit the page...

run this javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.open( '@HttpContext.Current.Session["EisUrl"].ToString();' );
    });


</script>
```

}

and instead of opening a new window pointing to google.com, I get the same window with this message.

The view 'http://google.com' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/ReportsManagement/http://google.com.aspx
~/Views/ReportsManagement/http://google.com.ascx
~/Views/Shared/http://google.com.aspx
~/Views/Shared/http://google.com.ascx
~/Views/ReportsManagement/http://google.com.cshtml
~/Views/ReportsManagement/http://google.com.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/http://google.com.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/http://google.com.vbhtml

So it's treating my external URL as if it's still internal to the website...

This seems like it ought to be pretty simple..... clearly I'm missing something obvious.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your jovialscript is hitting your ASP.NET MVC server, and trying to execute teh controllers.

Comment: @DarthVader What do you mean?  He accepts answers on 2/3 of the questions he asks.

Comment: Why negative rep? I answered it, it already has answers so I can't delete it, despite trying to... The behavior is illogical enough that someone else is likely to bump into it agian, so the answers might even be of help... I don't know what to have done differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i was being an id 10 t,

I had this in the view(razor)

```
@model string
```

and this in the controller

```
public ActionResult GetEisReportRedirect()
        {
            string url =  eisReportBLLHdl.DoGetEisReportRedirect(  );

            return View( url );// i was passing url here to the view
        }
```

So it' was trying to pass the string as a model, I decided i was unsure of the exact behavior and swapped to putting it in the session.. but left those in place.

For some reason, the string was getting interpteted as a URL, the fact that the new window was not openeing should have been a clue it was going off the rails early.

When I removed the line from the model and the url paramter from the return View()... it now redirects correctly (just not in a new page but I'll get that)

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure what is being rendered from the session is the correct and well-formed URL as you would expect. I normally use `window.location` to redirect in javascript also.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe totally out of scope, but can't you do this in the `ActionResult` ?

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, I need to open a new window which is then redirected to an external webpage (for testing google.com)

Answer (score 1):

try

`window.location = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["EisUrl"].ToString()';`

Comment: Tried Window.location, and it does the same thing. I am trying to open a new window and goto a url outside of my MVC app... what am I missing? I swear iI've done this before...

Comment: How do you set the Session variable?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session[ "EisUrl" ] = url;

Comment: It's toatlly brute force, trying to do everything simply string url = "http://google.com";

Comment: ok so rather do this: `url = "http://www.google.com";` . It wont open it in a new window though. For that you will need to stick to your `window.open` guns.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer, in short I was being a id 10 t